# Backbone: Can I get a collection of the model in which it is found?

Tags: backbone.js, collections, models

Can I get a collection of the model in which it is found?I would like to get a collection of models for calculating the preceding and following the model relative to the current. Can it be done in the Backbone?

```
var PhotoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: "media-item",
    template: _.template(photoItemTemplate),
    render: function(){
        var data, next;
        data = this.model.toJSON();

        this.$el.html(this.template(data));

        return this;
    },
    prev: function () {
        //this.model.collection = ??
    },
    next: function () {
       //this.model.collection = ??
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var collection = this.model.collection;
var prevModel = collection.at(collection.indexOf(this.model) - 1);
var nextModel = collection.at(collection.indexOf(this.model) + 1);
```

Comment: prevModel === undefined if collection.indexOf(this.model) - 1 is negative

Answer (score 0):

`this.model.collection` would give you the collection to which the model belongs too.

Comment: Thank you! Strangely, it is not described in the documentation.